# Jquery click selector and for loop madness in shopify

Tags: jquery, this, selector, each, shopify

I am trying to make a menu when you click on a link the submenu shows using jquery. the problem is that the submenus are coming from for loops in shopify.  So when I click on the trigger ALL submenus open, I think I need an each and  a this but not sure where here is some code:

```
<script>
            $(function(){
                $('.trigger').click(function(){
                    $('.accordion').show('fast');
                });
            });
          </script>

              <li class="trigger" ><a href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}" class="sub-menu {% if link.active %}active{% endif %} {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}{% if link.active %}active{% endif %}{% endfor %}">{{ link.title }} 
                <span class="arrow">▾</span></a> 
                <div class="dropdown {% if count.size > column_threshold %}dropdown-wide{% endif %}">
                  <ul >
                    {% assign count = 0 %}
                    {% assign split = false %}
                    {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}
                      {% capture count %}{{ count }}*{% endcapture %}
                      <li ><a   href="#" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a></li>
                       {% if linklists[link.handle] != empty %}
                    <li  class="accordion" style="display:none;">
                      {% for link in linklists[link.handle].links %}
                      <a  class="sub-link " href="{{ link.url }}" title="{{ link.title }}">{{ link.title }}</a>
                      {% endfor %} 
                    </li>
                       {% endif %}
```

There is more under this but that is irrelevant, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

I'm trying to understand what is going on based on the poor description as well as only including the code you think is relevant, but try this.

```
$('.trigger').on('click',function(e){
    var self = this;

    e.preventDefault();

    $(self).find('.sub-link[href="'+self.href+'"]').parent('.accordion').show('fast');
});
```

This will get the destination `href` from the `.trigger`, look for the `.sub-link` that has that same `href`, and open its `.accordion` parent.

If this still doesn't do what you are looking for, you might consider being more descriptive with the goal of the action.

Comment: I've edited my answer in another attempt to help, but remember garbage in garbage out. If it still doesn't do what you want, try providing the entirety of the code (we don't even see the end of the first `for` loop).